# Differential Equations (Proving)

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

This is the question --> [image]

---

What I have done;

$$  dS/dt = kS(N-S) $$

$$ 1/(S(N-S)) = k dt $$

$$ 1/(SN - S^2) = k dt $$

Therefore

$$ 1/(S-2S) * ln|SN-S^2| = kt + c $$

A I on the right track? if not could someone guide me..

Comment: may be $dS/$ instead of $1/$ ? also $\int \frac{1}{S (N-S)} \, dS=\frac{\ln (S)-\ln (S-N)}{N}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$s'(t)=ks(t)(n-s(t))\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\frac{s'(t)}{s(t)(n-s(t))}=k\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\int\frac{s'(t)}{s(t)(n-s(t))}\space\text{d}t=\int k\space\text{d}t\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\frac{\ln\left|s(t)\right|-\ln\left|s(t)-n\right|}{n}=kt+\text{C}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$s(t)=\frac{ne^{n\left(kt+\text{C}\right)}}{e^{kt+\text{C}}-1}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$s(t)=n+\frac{n}{e^{n\left(kt+\text{C}\right)}-1}$$

---

We know that $2$ students knew the rumour, at time $0$:

$$s(0)=2\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$2=n+\frac{n}{e^{n\left(k\cdot0+\text{C}\right)}-1}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$2=\frac{ne^{n\left(k\cdot0+\text{C}\right)}}{e^{k\cdot0+\text{C}}-1}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$2=\frac{ne^{n\left(0+\text{C}\right)}}{e^{0+\text{C}}-1}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$2=\frac{ne^{n\text{C}}}{e^{\text{C}}-1}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\text{C}=-\frac{\ln\left(\frac{2-n}{2}\right)}{n}$$

So:

$$s(t)=n+\frac{n}{e^{n\left(kt+\left(-\frac{\ln\left(\frac{2-n}{2}\right)}{n}\right)\right)}-1}=\frac{2ne^{knt}}{n+2e^{knt}-2}=\frac{n}{1+\frac{1}{2}e^{-knt}(n-2)}$$

Comment: Nice Answer!!!!